Why is my setInterval in a functional React component only changing a value once?
I try to change background-image using setInterval which is compileable, but the problem is, it only change once from image a.jpg to b.jpg.
here is my code ;

  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState<string>("/a.jpg");
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (currentImage === "/a.jpg") {
        setCurrentImage("/b.jg");
      } else if (currentImage === "/b.jpeg") {
        setCurrentImage("/c.jpg");
      } else {
        setCurrentImage("/a.jpg");
      }
    }, 6000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

how to correctly wrote setInterval in nextjs and make it return to starting image?

You're using the currentImage variable in the useEffect callback but since  you don't include it in the dependency array, it will always have its initial value ("/a.jpg") when useEffect invokes it. This is what's known as a stale reference.
To fix this you need to add currentImage to the dependency array so that the callback gets updated when it changes.
useEffect(() => {
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (currentImage === "/a.jpg") {
      setCurrentImage("/b.jg");
    } else if (currentImage === "/b.jpeg") {
      setCurrentImage("/c.jpg");
    } else {
      setCurrentImage("/a.jpg");
    }
  }, 6000);
  return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, [ currentImage ]);

Any variable that the useEffect callback uses must always be included in the dependency array
Note that this means that the "timer" will restart every time currentImage changes. If this is not acceptable, you'll need a more complex solution involving useRef.

Good point! I would also add that It's also a better idea to use the prev value instead of the currentImage using setCurrentImage(prev => prev === "/a.jpg" ? "/b.jpg" : (prev === "/b.jpeg" ? "/c.jpeg" : "a.jpeg"))

@ArashJahanBakhshan Thanks for that! That's an even better solution in this case to cycle through values.

Thank you for the solution and explanation. It really teach me something. I was also working on similar condition to change onclick handler using (let say) "to change image by changing select»option value containing useState", probably its going to be similar solutions.

Here is a way to handle your use case.  I'm not sure I'm advocating it, but it totally works.
const colorMap = {
"/a.jpg":"/b.jpg",
"/b.jpg":"/c.jpg",
"/c.jpg":"/a.jpg"
}


  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState<string>("/a.jpg");
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
     setCurrentImage(prevState => colorMap[prevState])
    }, 6000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

